# Severity Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: codeigniter

With some changes I got the error, This work fine in raw php but in codeigniter I'm trying to get this `result_array` in a while(list), but I don't know what would be the alternative for `fetch_row` in codeigniter. Please help me to get this in a way at `while (list($d, $sn, $s) = each($IDS-))` line.

**Model:**

```
 public function raw_attendance_Data() {
        $this->db->select('attnDate, TraineeID, Status');
        $this->db->from('tbl_attendance');
        $this->db->order_by('TraineeID');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function rawAttendance(){
        $data['IDS'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_Data();
        $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
    }
```

**View:**

```
$curname='';
    $tdata = '';
      reset($IDS);
      while (list($d, $sn, $s) = each($IDS)) {
            if ($curname != $sn) {
                if ($curname) {
                    $tdata .= "<tr><td>$curname</td><td>" . join('</td><td>', $rowdata). "</td></tr>\n";
                }
                $rowdata = $emptyRow;
                $curname = $sn;
            }
            $rowdata[$d] = $s;
        }
    $tdata .= "<tr><td>$curname</td><td>" . join('</td><td>', $rowdata). "</td></tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->result_array();` returns an array and not an object. Thus the `$IDS` in `$IDS->fetch_row()` is an array (a non-object).

I don't understand, where you are getting the function `fetch_row()`?

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish then this should work.

**View:**

```
  $tdata = '';

  foreach($IDS as $row)
  {
    $curname = isset($row['TraineeID']) ? $row['TraineeID'] : "";
    $date = isset($row['attnDate']) ? $row['attnDate'] : "";
    $status = isset($row['Status']) ? $row['Status'] : "";
    if(!empty($curname){
        $tdata .= "<tr><td>$curname</td><td>$date</td><td>$status</td></tr>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sir, I change my code `each($IDS)` instead of `fetch_row`. Please take a look.